# How to add clipping to border and text, not just text?

Tags: css

I am able to mask my `<h1>` text with an image like this:

```
h1{
  border: #efefef 5px solid;
  padding: 0.5em;

  /* clipping */
  background:url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/63/69/00/63690009a5fabbf80b921696218cba3f.jpg');
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  background-position:0 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  -moz-background-clip:text;
  background-clip:text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qaoun0ae/)

Which works perfectly on just the text I would also like to have the image mask over the border too is that possible and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it. Hope can help

```
border-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/63/69/00/63690009a5fabbf80b921696218cba3f.jpg') 30 round;
```